# EntityObject usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just got a DLL library to be used that has the following class documented:

Class definition:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName = "CustomerData", Name = "Customer")]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference = true)]
public class Customer : EntityObject
```

Class properties documentation:

```
Name: public string Name { get; set; }
Description: public string Description { get; set; }
EntityKey: Inherited from EntityObject
EntityState: Inherited from EntityObject
etc... (common properties)
```

Altough I can declare and use it, I´m guessing how does this class was built (EntityFramework?) and how to make use of the EntityKey and EntityState properties. Why is it inherited from EntityObject ?

All I have is the DLL and little reference.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this class comes from some version of Entity Framework.

I strongly suggest that you ignore those properties from the base class. They are specific to the implementation of the class and should almost certainly not be used.